# Updating component with async function in mithirl.js

Tags: javascript, async-await, mithril.js

I'm trying to get some initial data for a component using an async function oninit then updating 
that component each time 'Show more' button is clicked.

Here is the component:

```
const Listings = {
    oninit: async (vnode) => {
        vnode.state.data = await get_listings()
        console.log("Ok has data ", vnode.state.data)
    },
    view: vnode => {

        console.log("NOK undefined ", vnode.state.data)

        return m("section.anunturi.mb-4", [

            vnode.state.data.map(data => {
                return m("span", JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2))
            }),

            m("button", {class:"btn", onclick:get_listings}, "Show more")
        ])
    }
}
```

oninit gets the data from the async function but is not saved in vnode.state.data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. on first load the data is not ready right away and so data is undefined and throws a javascript error, add a condition to prevent displaying the data until the data is ready `vnode.state.data ? /* display it */ : /* display loading message */`
2. once the data becomes ready you need to tell mithril to redraw, [redraw], by calling `m.redraw()`, I added that call at the end of `oninit`, which based on Mozilla's async/await documentation should be treated as the contents of a `then()` function of a `promise` ([async], ie. called after the awaited data is back

[async] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

[redraw] https://mithril.js.org/redraw.html

```
const Listings = {
    oninit: async (vnode) => {
        vnode.state.data = await get_listings()
        console.log("Ok has data ", vnode.state.data)
        m.redraw();
    },
    view: vnode => {

        console.log("NOK undefined ", vnode.state.data)

        return m("section.anunturi.mb-4", [

            vnode.state.data ? vnode.state.data.map(data => {
                return m("span", JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2))
            }) : "Waiting for data...",

            m("button", {class:"btn", onclick:get_listings}, "Show more")
        ])
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a bit of an issue with this implementation, even if it solves the problem at hand; Lifecycle methods in Mithril 2.x are not async/await compatible (outside of onbeforeremove) and works here slightly by circumstance. A working simulation can be found here (flems.io) tinyurl.com/y96hfl8k .

Outside of this, the community at large has also taken to prefer the closure syntax for components in general. :) Feel free to pop by the chat, there's usually someone around to answer questions gitter.im/mithriljs/mithril.js

Comment: ... prefer the closure syntax for _stateful_ components in general, rather.